# How can i call function with structure in c++

Tags: c++

Can anybody help me with the following code. I have declared one structure inside namespace nad structure contains one function. How can I call `fun()` in the code.

```
namespace aaa {
  struct bbb {
    void fun();
  }
}
```

Comment: `aaa::bbb b; b.fun();`

Answer (score 1):

`fun` is a non-static member function, which means you need an instance of it:

```
aaa::bbb x;
x.fun();
```

Comment: i want to call fun() without declaring an instance.

Comment: @user2658467 then you make it a `static` member function: `struct bbb { static void fun(); };` and then call it with `bbb::fun()`.